# JS Object property inheritance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can't understand the rules here for JS class/object property inheritance. Suppose the example:

```js
class Foo {}

Foo.myName = 'foo'
Foo.stats = {
  fooStat: 2
}

class Bar extends Foo {}

Bar.myName = 'bar';
Bar.stats.barStat = 55;


console.log(Foo.myName)
console.log(Bar.myName)

console.log(Foo.stats)
console.log(Bar.stats)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzjuo5u4/

What I expect:

1. For `name` to be 'foo' and 'bar' respectively
2. For `stats` to be unchanged for `Foo`, but to have an extra property for `Bar`

Why is #1 true, but #2 is not? What is special about a property that is an object (or array, apparently) versus a primitive property?

Comment: `Foo` and `Bar` are two separate function objects. The functions themselves don't have an inheritance relationship. There's nothing special about a property holding an object in this regard. For the primitive, you provided both function objects their own value. For the object, you only placed the object on `Foo`, so it doesn't exist on `Bar`.

Comment: ...even if there was such a relationship, if you altered the object on `Bar` the change would be visible from `Foo`, because you'd still be mutating the same object.

Comment: Why would they not assign `Bar` a unique clone of `Foo`s `stats` property? Why reference the original? This is not how classes behave in other languages.

Comment: Other languages are irrelevant to how JS is designed.

Comment: Not really. Do you pick up a new language by forgetting everything you know from others?

Comment: @yallo: Yes, or at least being able to understand that a different language is called a different language for a reason. There may be *some* overlap, but there should be no expectation of direct translation.

Comment: @squint I care because I see it constantly and it's infuriating. It essentially prevents new users from gaining rep, since they don't receive any from people providing answers or being able to select a correct one.

Comment: if you're going to answer the question, answer the question. If you need more clarity or would like to comment on the question, comment on the question.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @briceshatzer: Rep is nothing to be infuriated about. It's worthless. And putting information in comments doesn't prevent answers.

Comment: @squint it's absolutely something to be infuriated about when it's actively used as way of preventing new users from being able to fully participate on the site.

Comment: @squint ...you know how this [site works right](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)?

Comment: @briceshatzer Lets stop flooding question with non-constructive comments. Both of you are right in your perspective but in my understanding, its not infuriating. I have pointed out many optimisations/ corrections on answer added by users with 50x rep then me. This portal is about knowledge and if you are right, people will appreciate.

Comment: @briceshatzer: Of course. That changes nothing. People can still post answers. Nobody is prevented from participating.

Comment: @Rajesh it's not a matter of people have low rep making corrections on those with high. Users aren't even allowed to make those sort of comments until they achieve an adequate level of reputation. By answering new users questions via comments it denies them the only method they have of attaining that level. 

That being said, I'll leave it alone :)

Answer (score 0):

`Foo` and `Bar` are two separate function objects. The functions themselves don't have an inheritance relationship. There's nothing special about a property holding an object in this regard. For the primitive, you provided both function objects their own value. For the object, you only placed the object on `Foo`, so it doesn't exist on `Bar` even if there was such a relationship, if you altered the object on `Bar` the change would be visible from `Foo`, because you'd still be mutating the same object

*via @squint in the comments*